# standard names for ontologies IRI(s) with version and dates

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, ontology, iri

I've read here https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#IRIs that an Ontology's IRI should (not must) have a date and a version

I tried to follow the examples there and I found that they are doing the following for IRI

```
"<http://" +"mywebsitename" + ".com or .org or .whatever" + "//" + "year" + "/" + "month" + "day"+ "/" + "the name of the ontology" + "#>"
```

my question is that correct? so where do I put the version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  may be missing part of the document that you're citing, but I don't see any recommendation that "Ontology's IRI should (not must) have a date and a version".  That said, it's a useful convention, but note that with OWL 2, there can be *two*  IRIs associated with a particular ontology.  One is the ontology IRI, which as you say, doesn't typically have version/date/etc., information available in it.  The second is the (optional) ontology version IRI. The specification for the functional-style syntax is:

> ```
> Ontology :=
>     'Ontology' '(' [ ontologyIRI [ versionIRI ] ]
>        directlyImportsDocuments
>        ontologyAnnotations
>        axioms
>     ')'
> ```

I think it'd be more common to do something like

```
Ontology( <http://example.org/llamas>
          <http://example.org/llamas/2016/02/26>
          ... )
```

where http://example.org/llamas is the ontology IRI, and http://example.org/llamas/2016/02/26 is the ontology version IRI.  But what you use for a version IRI (and for the ontology IRI, too, for that matter) is really up to you.  If you look around, you can find some conventions, but IRIs are opaque, there's not a mandatory way to encode that information.

Comment: thanks for answering, is `llamas` in your example the *name of the ontology* so to speak? like if i am using a musical ontolgoy, will this IRI be follow the convention? http://mywebsite.org/musicalontolgoy ?

Comment: @AniaDavid Again, IRIs are sort of opaque, and ontologies aren't identified by *names*; they're identified by IRIs.  If you have a "name" for an ontology, then you probably want to consider putting it into the IRI somewhere, but that's really up to you.  E.g., you could call you musical ontology `http://example.org/88ashjk325`, if you want.

Comment: i really appreciate your help, it is like this website just you and me :) no other people are interested in semantic web, i don't know why. thank you again, i hope someday i help you back.

Comment: @AniaDavid: not true that other people are not interested in SemWeb - at least I am :) - but not everyone is checking StackOverflow every day. also, if a question already has a good answer there is not much to add.

Comment: @CaptSolo that is right, but it is also correct that the number of users are less comparing to tags like java where if you asked a question, more people will view and answer. look at my profile, today i asked three questions since the morning, and I've been updating them requlary adding what I'm trying, and yet not just no one answered, but not more than 2 users have seen the questions :). Anyway, I hope this subject becomes more popular and I hope I will study more to be like you guys, helping users (i really hope)

Comment: @AniaDavid you may also ask these questions on http://answers.semanticweb.com/ - it's smaller than StackOverflow but fully dedicated to Semantic Web

Comment: I agree with @captsolo on that one; I used to spend more time on answers.semanticweb.com. it's a good community, though the site itself is not quite as polished as Stack Overflow, and has intermittent reliability issues.